# Issue with Quit application menu in cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a cocoa application running on Mac OS 10.6.8
I am adding an entry to apple menu in the app, for quitting my application. The code is like this:

`item = [menu addItemWithTitle: @"Quit Myapp" , NSLocalizedString(@"Quit", nil), applicationName] action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];`

`[item setTarget:NSAPP];`

Now, my problem is that when a modal dialog is opened using `runModal` of `NSOpenPanel`, this quit menu item is still enabled. Rest of the menu items are disabled as usual. I am not able to understand why.

If I change the above code so that menu item's target is not NSApp, but another cocoa object, then the problem disappears.

Could someone please let me know if it is a known issue. Is it wrong to set the NSApp as a menu item's target?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Application Menu from Interface Builder?

Comment: I have my own customized class inherited from NSMenuItem. I am adding all the menu items programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that doing this is probably a bad idea.  That said, set (or leave) the target as `nil` to target the responder chain.  That will probably make it disable when a model window is up.

Update:

Hmm.  Checking a new MainMenu NIB, I see that the Quit menu item does actually target the application object.  So, that may not be the issue.

By the way, in the code snippets above, you're targeting `NSAPP`, whatever that is, rather than `NSApp`.

Also, the argument list to `-addItemWithTitle:...` is all messed up and makes no sense.  You should clean up your question to reflect actual code.